# Remove second directory from url htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi guys I would like to remove the second directory from a url like https://www.example.com.au/products/mopod/MP15/? to https://www.example.com.au/products/MP15/?

by the way /mopod/MP15 is generated by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, you must first enable `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` in your `httpd.conf`.

Then, you can rewrite a URL to "remove" a given directory by adding the example below to your `.htaccess` in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. In this example, `mopod` is the folder you wish to be hidden:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/products/mopod/(.*)$ /products/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

**Explanation:** The above rules find any URL matching products/mopod/*, and move the files at * into $1's location. We then make a redirection to /products/$1.

```
These are the flags used:
L  - Last
NC - No Case comparison
R  - External Redirection
```

For completion sake, because you have not specified what web server you are using, an example for IIS is also given below (whereby `mopod` is the folder to be removed). You can ignore this if my assumption that you are using Apache is correct.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="removefolder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^/products/mopod/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/products/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I see that you are new to Stack Overflow. Welcome!

If this answers your question please remember to mark my answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for answering @scarfe but it doesn't work.. Yes where using Apache Version 2.4.25 .
I guest it has something to do with the wordpress plugin I'm using that generate the url for single page product.

Also thank you for welcoming. Yup I'm new here..

Comment: Looking into this for you now. Just to confirm, you have definitely enabled mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf correct?